# When I run my code the only number that appears on the screen is the number that I entered. How do I get this to work?

Tags: function, loops, numbers, call, void

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void primefunction(int);

int main()
{
    char response = 'y';
    while (response == 'y')
        do
        {
        int num;
        int i;
        cout << "Please enter a number that is greater than or equal to 2 \n";
        cin >> num;
        cout << "The number you entered was " << num << ".\n";
        for (i = 2; i < num; i++); 
            primefunction(i);
        cout << "Would you like to run the program again? \n"
            << "Enter y for yes or n for no: ";
        cin >> response;
        } while (response == 'Y' || response == 'y');
    return 0;
}
void primefunction(int j)
{
    int divisior = 2;
    int stat = 0;
    while (divisior < j && stat == 0)
    {
        if (j%divisior == 0);
            stat = 1;
        divisior++;
    }
    if (stat == 0)
        cout << j;
    return;


}
```

When my teacher went over this example in class, I made sure to copy every part of the code that I had done wrong to make it right. But at this point it only out puts a number instead of all the prime numbers up to the number that was inserted. How can I fix this problem? Am I not sending the right number to the void function or am I calling the void function wrong? I am unsure.

Comment: `cout << j` are you sure that you want to print `j` here?

Comment: I'm not sure. Should I place it in main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are extra semicolons at the end of the for statement in the main function, and there is also an semicolon at the end of the "if (j%divisior == 0 )"

Remove these and see if that changes anything.